# jqTransform Autosubmit

Tags: jquery, submit, onchange, jqtransform

I am trying to implement autosubmit on a jqTransformSelect. I have tried

```
$("div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").click(function(){     
  $("select-form").submit();            
  return false;
});
```

But I've failed miserably. Am I doomed to drop jqTransform or is there a hack for this script?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be an ID:

```
$("#select-form").submit();
```

Note the "#" at the beginning of the selector. Currently you're matching a tag.